# Postman gives There was an error in evaluating the test script: JSONError: No data, empty input at 1:1 ^ error

Tags: api-testing, postman

I'm trying to create a postman script that sends an SMS message to a phone. When I send the message I get this error:

```
There was an error in evaluating the test script:  JSONError: No data, empty input at 1:1 ^
```

This is all I have in my prereq scripts:

```
const dateNow = new Date();
postman.setGlobalVariable("currentDate", dateNow.toISOString())
pm.environment.set("MSISDN", "+15555555555");
pm.environment.set("%2BMSISDN", "%2B15555555555");
```

This is the script:

```
var data = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("msgID", data.RCSMessage.msgId);

pm.test("Status code is 202; msgId is " + data.RCSMessage.msgId, function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(202);
});
```

This is the body of the script:

```
{
    "RCSMessage": {
        "textMessage": "SD Smoke Test Message - {{currentDate}}"
    },
    "messageContact": {
        "userContact": "{{MSISDN}}"
    }
}
```

The script is communicating with a bot I have setup as an environment that will send a message to a phone. I have that environment selected.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: My guess is you have some Javascript in the Tests scripts, but you're getting no answer, or empty body in the response. Post your request and response from Postman console to your question.

Comment: Error is not in prerequisites , it's in test script . Add test script to your question

Comment: Hi, I've added the body of the script. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is the request body, now post the rest. Request, response, and Tests script.

Comment: Ok sorry I am new to postman. How would I do that?

Comment: @user99201 goto test tab and copy the code you have there , ! how are you writing tests if you don't know what is pre-requisit and test scripts

Comment: @user99201: Postman provides good documentation/learning sites, you can learn more from here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/intro-to-scripts/

Comment: I've updated the post with the script I'm using.

Comment: @user99201: your error is caused by `var data = pm.response.json();` because you  get no response.That's why I also asked you about the response. But anyway, if you want to get rid of the error, you delete what you have in Tests, although you probably still want to have the check that the API accepted your request. The real problem you have is why you're not getting 202 status code and some reasonable response body. Is your API request working? I mean do you get the SMS?

Comment: @pavelsaman ok thanks. I think at this point, the problem is in the environment that I'm testing. Because I tried the same exact same script in another environment and I was able to get a valid response back. Thanks for your help.